# Typescript - Property does not exist on type 'xxx[]'

Tags: typescript

I have an array `partialClassList` that consists of objects that look like this:

```
{
  resultsPerTopic: [
    {topic: "Some topic", total: 1, points: 0}
  ],
  code: "B"
}
```

I have declared the interface for that array like this:

```
interface IPartialClass {
  code: string,
  resultsPerTopic: ITopic[]
}

interface ITopic {
  topic: string,
  correct: number,
  total: number,
  points: number,
}
```

And in my code I am trying to map and go through the partialClassList array like this:

```
result.partialClassList.resultsPerTopic.map((topic, index)
```

The interface for the result looks like this:

```
interface IResultModel {
  data: IKeyValue[],
  topic: ITopic[],
  combo: boolean,
  partialClassList: IPartialClass[]
}
```

But, I get the error:

```
Property 'resultsPerTopic' does not exist on type 'IPartialClass[]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

With `result.partialClassList.resultsPerTopic.map((topic, index)`, you would go through the resultsPerTopic list. But partialClassList is an array and doesn't have a resultsPerTopic attribute.

You must first go through the partialClassList : `result.partialClassList.map(p => ...`

Answer (score 0):

`partialClassList` is an array, you need to provide an index

`result.partialClassList[i].resultsPerTopic.map((topic, index)`